# how to set background color on basis of css-counter of divs

Tags: css, sass, css-counter

I have a set of data rows, each row shown as a tile of (label + value). I am wrapping them in a `div.tilemap-tile`

```
<div class="tilemap">
  <div class="tilemap-tile" ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy: 'value'">
    <div class="data-label">{{x.label}}</div>
    <div class="data-value">{{x.value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show this in a Nx3 or Nx4 styled grid such that - (a) the label for each row begins with a different color from a palette, and (b) the labels for subsequent tiles in the same row are successively darker.

I can get the grid visual by adjusting the tile properties

```
  .tilemap-tile {
    counter-reset: Z 0;
    clear: both;
    .tilemap-tile {
      counter-increment: Z;
      width: 33%;
      display: table-cell;
      float: left;
      vertical-align: top;
      height: 5em;
      .data-label {
        @include tile-bgcolor(red, counter(Z)); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM
      }
    }
  }
```

What I am struggling with is how to set the background of the `data-label`. I tried the following but it appears that `counter` can only be used within `contents` property. As a result, the computation below gives a sass error.

```
@mixin tile-bgcolor($basecolor, $p) {
  $c: darken($basecolor, ($p % 3) * 5%);   <<<<<<<<< $p is not numeric
  &::after { content: "(debug, tile# " $p; };   <<<<< shows values 1..N
  background: $c;
  foobar: $p;                              <<< shows in browser as "counter(Z)"
}
```

Is there any other DRY way of keeping track of "div.tilemap-tile" count and using that in bg-color computations?

UPDATE

I don't know how to respond to "already has an answer" link but although helpful it is clearly not an answer. Please see my question again for the two specific requirements. Based on @cinnamon's comments, I don't think there is a pure-SASS/CSS answer.

Comment: You understand that `counter(Z)` is a CSS construct and cannot be used from Sass, right?  Because Sass is compiled before it is ever sent to the browser.

Comment: That's what I had thought too, that `counter(Z)` will be determined at runtime and Sass will create some fancy `calc` statement to compute the color. But I see from your comment I misunderstood.

Comment: @cimmanon even if I add a property to `.data-label{ foo: counter(Z);}` it shows in browser verbatim while I expected it to be an increasing number. So, is `counter(Z)` not usable in calculations?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  As far as Sass is concerned `counter(Z)` is a string that is to be output verbatim.  You can't do anything with it from Sass other than treat it like any other ordinary string.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear enough. I get that about Sass; I tried to use `counter(Z)` in something like `rgb( calc( 10 * counter(Z) ), 100, 100 )` but that also failed, asking for a numeric input for $red.

Comment: Uh huh?  `rgb()` is a Sass function.  It expects you to pass either a color or 3 numbers to it.  A string is neither of those.

Comment: See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984021

Answer (score 0):

@cimmanon points out that you cannot use counter() in SASS because it is a CSS function, not a SASS function. Your browser will understand it, but the SASS compiler just outputs it as a string. However, you can approximate what you need with SASS and `nth-child`. If you have a palette like:

```
// add as many colors as you want; colors will repeat
$palette: (#EBE998, #D1D6B5, #A1BEC6, #777FC0, #59546A);
```

Then, for each color output an `nth-child` rule. (I'm using a table as my markup but you get the idea).

```
$i : 1;
@each $color in $palette{
    // select every [length of list]th table row, starting with first, second, etc
    tr:nth-child(#{length($palette)}n + #{$i}){
        background-color: $color;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
}
```

The darkening along the rows is a little more of a hack...basically use a second element (in my case, the `td`s inside the rows but you can adjust to your markup), and use a progressively less-transparent black background color:

```
// assumes you'll have a max of 20 columns in the table
@for $i from 1 through 20{
    td:nth-child(#{$i}){
        background-color: opacify(rgba(0,0,0,0), $i*.04)
    }   
}
```

Here's a demonstration on codepen: http://codepen.io/noraspice/pen/doEyJq?editors=110.

Comment: I ended up using a custom javascript function. One material difference in using div's versus tr's is that with tr's the CSS engine can tell you the row number. But I could not make it adaptive to different display sizes that way.